# Burnt wire in GE stove

Tags: electrical, stove, range, fire-hazard, fire

I spilled some water on the knobs of my GE stove. 5 minutes later, I heard some buzzing and then there was a brief fire from a knob for 30 seconds. I turned off the gas and electricity, opened the stove, and saw that the wire from that knob to its indicator light was completely fried. The rest is fine, and the stove works fine except for that light.

Do I need to remove the wire to the light? Or can I leave it there without danger. I’m fine with the current function of the stove without that indicator light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wire is fried, it's probably weak and should be removed and replaced. The indicator lights serve as a safety device to give you a visual that the oven/stove is on. It would not be wise to just disconnect it. Cut the burnt piece of wire and disconnect it from the light and take it to an appliance repair shop to get the proper heat range wire and connector. Then hook it back up with a wire nut. Never smart to bypass safety lights, someone could get burned real bad or it could just start a fire.